# something wrong with JOGL (eclipse)

Tags: java, jar, jogl

In Eclipse all run fine, but in export jar:C:\wamp\www\JOGL>java -jar test.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLEventListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
Could not find the main class: windows.SimpleScene. Program will exit.
```

Project folder:

```
C:\WAMP\WWW\JOGL
├───.settings
├───bin
│   └───windows![enter image description here][1]
├───jogl-2.0-b11
│   ├───etc
│   ├───jar
│   ├───jnlp-files
│   └───lib
└───src
    └───windows
```

IDE Screenshot:

http://i.piccy.info/i5/40/33/1183340/Properties_for_JOGL.png

JAR (7zip)

http://i.piccy.info/i5/38/33/1183338/CwampwwwJOGLtest.jar.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java -Djava.library.path="lib" -cp test.jar:jar/jogl.all.jar:jar/newt.all.jar:jar/nativewindow.all.jar mypackage.MyJOGLApp
```

should work. The exception told you that jogl wasn't in the classpath (-cp argument). After that you would get a lib loading exception since no native libs would be in the lib path (-Djava.library.path property)

[edit] on windows use ';' as path seperator instead of ':'